# Want to fetch data from firestore to my ionic 4 app

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, modal-dialog, ionic4

I was able to upload some data to my firestore account, but i can't fetch or read the data. I'm new and will appreciate if i am guided like a newbie.

```
     ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingservice.read_AcBookings().then(data =>
     this.booking = data.map(e => {
      return {
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        isEdit: false,
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        firstname: e.payload.doc.data()['firstname'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        lastname: e.payload.doc.data()['lastname'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        phonenumber: e.payload.doc.data()['phonenumber'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        address: e.payload.doc.data()['address'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        location: e.payload.doc.data()['location'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        date: e.payload.doc.data()['date'],
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        servicebooked: e.payload.doc.data()['servicebooked'],

      };
    }));
    console.log(this.booking);

  }
```

This is the service

```
 read_AppliancesBookings() {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.afAuth.user.subscribe(currentUser => {
    if (currentUser) {
this.snapshotChangesSubscription = this.firestore.collection('Bookings').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('Appliances Bookings')
.snapshotChanges();
resolve(this.snapshotChangesSubscription);
    }
  });
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the output for ```console.log(this.booking);``` ?

Comment: An Undefined result and also data.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

There are a few fundamental mistakes in your `bookingservice`, so I just rewrote it for you. Hopefully you can learn what was wrong by looking at this code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { reject } from 'q';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class bookingservice {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  userId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

  read_AppliancesBookings() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.firestore
            .doc<any>(`Bookings/${userId}`)
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe(doc => {
              resolve(doc);
            });
        }).then((result) => {
          return result;
        });

  }


}
```

Let me know if that works.